# GSON outputs null array values

Tags: java, gson

This is my GSON instance as you can see no serializeNulls().

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().create();
```

This is how I generate json:

```
object.add("inventory", GSON.toJsonTree(inventory.getItems()));
```

Item:

```
private int id;
private int amount;

public Item(int id, int amount) {
    this.id = id;
    this.amount = amount;
}
```

Output:

```
"inventory": [
{
  "id": 13
  "amount": 1,
},
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null,
null
],
```

I also tried creating an adapter but no luck:

```
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(Item src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    System.out.println(src); // This only prints valid values, no nulls...

    return new Gson().toJsonTree(src, src.getClass());
}
```

Why does the output contain nulls and how can I get rid of those?

Comment: How many items do you have in this `inventory.getItems()` list? I can see it has converted one element correctly to JSON.

Comment: It's able to convert all of the non null elements properly. For testing I only had one item.

Comment: So you just want to skip the `null` values?

Comment: Yes. However I'm not sure if it's possible with arrays.

Comment: Probably you have not written a correct Adaptor. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a custom JSON Serializer Adaptor like this:

```
public class CustomJsonArraySerializer<T> implements JsonSerializer<T[]> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(T[] source, Type type, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
        for(T item : source){
            if(item != null) { // skip null values
                jsonArray.add(context.serialize(item));
            }
        }
        return jsonArray;
    }
}
```

And you can register this custom serializer adopter like this:

```
private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Item[].class, new CustomJsonArraySerializer<>()).create();
```

Now when you will serialize the `Item[]` it will ignore the `null` values.

**Testing:**

```
Item[] items = {new Item(10, 20), null, null, null, new Item(50, 60)};
JsonElement jsonElement = GSON.toJsonTree(items);
System.out.println(jsonElement);
```

**Output:**

```
[{"id":10,"amount":20},{"id":50,"amount":60}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for until I realized I needed the slots for the inventory.. So in the end I used a HashMap and stored the slots as keys. However I will make great use of this for other stuff!

Comment: @Indrz You're welcome. And probably it will be useful for someone else who would be looking for such functionality in the future.